# How to find time spent by mappers and reducers in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

How to find time spent by each mapper and reducer as well as time for shuffling (sorting)  within the code (not in web interface) in Hadoop? How about total time by all mapper (or reducers?

Comment: The current answer lists a way with the java api. It may be nice to know if this is something we can access via command line as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an API for the `JobTracker` as described [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.html) which gives you a bunch of information on the cluster itself as well as details for all jobs.

In particular, if you know the job id and you want to find metrics for each individual map and reduce tasks, you could call `getMapTaskReports` which will return a `TaskReport` instance detailed [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskReport.html) which gives you access to methods such as `getFinishTime` or `getStartTime`. So for example:

```
TaskReport[] maps = jobtracker.getMapTaskReports("your_job_id");
for (TaskReport rpt : maps) {
  long duration = rpt.getFinishTime() - rpt.getStartTime();
  System.out.println("Mapper duration: " + duration);
}
TaskReport[] reduces = jobtracker.getReduceTaskReports("your_job_id");
for (TaskReport rpt : reduces) {
  long duration = rpt.getFinishTime() - rpt.getStartTime();
  System.out.println("Reducer duration: " + duration);
}
```

To count the total time by all mappers or reducers in your job, you could just sum them up simply in the code.

And regarding the shuffling, this is generally counted in the jobtracker as 33% of each reduce task, which does not necessarily mean it's 33% of the time but I don't think there's an automated way to get the shuffling time per task so you could just go with this simple heuristic with 33%.

Please take into account though that by using time measurements from the jobtracker API like shown above, the time in reducers might be a bit biased, because when a reduce task starts it essentially does the shuffling (up to 33% as explained), then **it waits** until all map tasks are finished, and only then does it start the actual reduce, so a reduce measurement is actually the sum of these 3 periods (shuffle + wait + reduce).

Comment: Thanks. My main program has a loop which executes a hadoop job in each iteration. So, how can I get the job id automatically within the code?

Comment: Besides, when I use "System.out.println()", where should I look for the output? (cause it does not print into the console obviously)

Comment: @Hessam I saw you posted another question about this so I replied here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761799/how-to-find-job-id-of-a-hadoop-job-in-code . And you don't need to print the statistics you get from the jobtracker API, you can just call this once you grabbed the job id and do whatever you want with it after.

Comment: thank. but can you see this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778939/submitting-a-hadoop-job

Comment: Could you clarify whether `getStartTime()` and `getFinishTime()` report time in milliseconds or some other unit?