# How to find job Id of a hadoop job in code?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a Hadoop program which has a loop. In each iteration of the loop a job is created. How can I find the job id in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit your `Job` instance, you can get information about the job id using the `getJobID` method:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
Job job = new Job(config);
// configure your job
job.submit();
// at that point your job is submitted but not finished and should have your job id
String jobid = job.getJobID().toString();
```

Note that there was a bug described in [MAPREDUCE-118](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-118) which impacted Hadoop versions before 0.20.204 where `getJobID` would only return `null`.