# How to get the ID of MapReduce job submitted by the `hadoop jar <example.jar> <main-class>` command?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a shell script which submits a MapReduce job by the command `hadoop jar <example.jar> <main-class>`, then how can I get the ID of the job submitted by that command in the shell script, right after that command was invoked?

I know that the command `hadoop job -list` can display all jobs' IDs, but in that case I can't tell which job is submitted by the shell script.

Comment: Is parsing job id from execution logs feasible?. If Yes , you can log the job id in driver code and parse it from logs. Refer to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761799/how-to-find-job-id-of-a-hadoop-job-in-code

Comment: It is possible to do so, but I don't think it is a good idea and an elegant manner.