# Submitting a Hadoop job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to constantly get the mappers' and reducers' running time. I have submitted the job as follows.

```
 JobClient jobclient = new JobClient(conf);
 RunningJob runjob = jobclient.submitJob(conf);          


 TaskReport [] maps = jobclient.getMapTaskReports(runjob.getID());

 long mapDuration = 0;
 for(TaskReport rpt: maps){
    mapDuration += rpt.getFinishTime() - rpt.getStartTime();
 }
```

However when I run the program, it seems like the job is not submitted and the mapper never starts. How can I use `JobClient.runJob(conf)` and still be able to get the running time?

Answer (score 1):

The `submitJob()` method returns control immediately to the calling program without waiting for the hadoop Job to start, much less complete.  If you want to wait then use the `waitForCompletion()` method which returns only after the hadoop job has finished.  I think you want something in between since you want to run subsequent code after the submit but before the complete.

I suggest you put your follow-on code in a loop that continues until the job is complete (Use the `isComplete()` method for that test) and observe the mappers and reducers as the job progresses.  You probably want to put a Thread.sleep(xxx) in the loop somewhere, too.

To respond to your comment, you want to...

```
job.waitForCompletion();
TaskCompletionEvent event[] = job.getTaskCompletionEvents();
for (int i = 0; i < event.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Task "+i+" took "+event[i].getTaskRunTime()+" ms");
}
```

Comment: What I exactly need is the total time for mappers (and reducers) when the job is done. That is, I need information which can be found in the jobtracker web interface.